# Detecting prefixes in a text file

Tags: java, arrays, matcher

I am trying to catch all of the words that contain certain 4 letter prefixes in a whole text file. These prefixes are specified as an array list called "keywordList". The way the code is currently, I am catching all of the words that need to be caught (that contain any of the prefixes in the Array List "keywordList"), however, I get duplicates and for some reason sometimes it prints blank line(s) after it prints one of the words detected. In other words, the pattern in which the output is printed does not have any uniformity.

**Console Output:**

```
Result: 
Result:APXP5558899
Result: 
Result: 
Result:IGC088838383833
Result: 
Result:CDAV
Result: 
Result:ASHGJHSGDSAGD
Result: 
Result:MOE1477347384
Result: 
Result:GHTS348939438
Result:ASHGJHSGDSAGD
Result: 
Result:MOE1477347384
Result: 
Result:GHTS348939438
Result:EGLVxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Result: 
Result:ESLVililillililil
Result: 
Result:HYSC999xxx
Result:
```

**I would like it to print to the results like this:**

```
Result:APXP5558899
Result:IGC088838383833
Result:CDAV
Result:ASHGJHSGDSAGD
Result:MOE1477347384
Result:GHTS348939438
Result:ASHGJHSGDSAGD
Result:EGLVxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Result:ESLVililillililil
Result:HYSC999xxx
```

**Text File contents:**

```
jkjfkjkjfkjkf jkjkfiiiiidijdjd
ddffdf
ddjjdkkii
jjjjd
sdhfjhdsfhjdsh APXP5558899 fdfsdsfsfsfgsfsdg
asjhdjsahjdhjsahd IGC088838383833 lllllllllpppppssss
JIJSIJSIJSJISJS
CDAV 337990099
kkkkkksslslsls
ASHGJHSGDSAGD MOE1477347384 GHTS348939438

EGLVxxxxxxxxxxxxx ESLVililillililil jdjdjdjdjdjdjddjdj
HYSC999xxx  6969696969696
```

**My Current Code:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class searchPdftext
{
public static ArrayList<String> keywordList;
public static String []  TestArray;
public static String Possibilities;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{

    //Possibilities =  keyword : TestArray;// i took out an =
    int tokencount;

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("EvergreenDME.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String s = "";
  int linecount = 0;      
  keywordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("APXP",  "IGC0", "CDAV",  "COSB", 
         "ESLV",  "2ISU",  "SUDU",  "5BUT", "HYSC", 
         "BNGF", "45HG", "NBCH", "MOE1", "RFGD",
         "GHTS"));  


    String line;
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] lineWordList = s.split(" ");
        for (String word : lineWordList) {

             for (String keyword : keywordList) {
                 if (word.contains(keyword)) {
                     //System.out.println(s);
                     test(s);
                     break;


                 }
             }
         }
     }
}


private static void test(String text) {
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b"+keywordList+".*?\\b").matcher(text);//"\\bABC123.*?\\b"____Word boundary // (?<=^|\s)ABC123\S*__For White spaces
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Result:" + m.group()) ;
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Result:" + m.group()) ;//System.out.println("Result:" + m.group() +" ");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Not found: " + text);
}
}
}
```

Comment: If keywordList contains prefixes, you probably want to use startsWith instead of contains, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: It seems you have the solution already, you don't need the test()-function, and in your innner loop, print `word` instead of `s`. (But your example output contains words which doesn't contain any of your keywordList-items)